# Hyper-v guests with no internet connection on default switch

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, hyper-v

I faced a crash with my current installation of Win 10, and found an older installation in my multiboot menu that I decided to start using instead. Upgraded it to 1909, and everything works fine except for:
Hyper-V (two simultaneous instances) used to connect through my VPN running on the host whenever it´d be enabled, and directly through the network adapter (wired) when not.
The only thing I can use to get an internet connection now is when directly connecting through the network adapter, "external" as they call it. But I want it to work as it did before. If I use the default switch, I get no internet: Chrome will tell me that "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET".
Any idea to set this up so that it does what I want it to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like firewalls were blocking - things are running now!

Comment: @zx485 This does provide an answer to the question, and in fact it's a self-answer by the author of the question.

Comment: I apologize. Unformtunately I don't know how to retract the vote.